# How to combine three if statements in jquery such that it passes a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery where I use the isScrolledIntoView to add or remove class

```
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
      if (elem.length > 0) {
        docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
        elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
      }
    }

    if (isScrolledIntoView($('.wrapper.site-section:nth-child(1)')) === true) {
      if ($('.desktop').length > 0) {
        $('.sidebar li').removeClass('showAdvertisement');
        $('.sidebar li:nth-child(4)').addClass('showAdvertisement');
      }
    }

    if (isScrolledIntoView($('.wrapper .site-section:nth-child(2)')) === true) {
      if ($('.desktop').length > 0) {
        $('.sidebar li').removeClass('showAdvertisement');
        $('.sidebar li:nth-child(5)').addClass('showAdvertisement');
      }
    }

    if (isScrolledIntoView($('.wrapper .site-section:nth-child(3)')) === true) {
      if ($('.desktop').length > 0) {
        $('.sidebar li').removeClass('showAdvertisement');
        $('.sidebar li:nth-child(6)').addClass('showAdvertisement');
      }
    }
```

I find the three if loops yucky. I will like to make it in a function. How to do that such that I can pass in variable (1,2,3) and then just use n+3 to call the inside?

Answer (score 1):

To DRY this up you could select the first 3 elements and loop through them all using `each()`. You can also check `$('.desktop').length > 0` outside of the loop as it's not affected by anything inside the looping logic. Try this:

```
var hasDesktop = $('.desktop').length > 0;
$('.wrapper.site-section:lt(4)').each(function(i) {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($(this)) && hasDesktop) {
    $('.sidebar li').eq(i + 4).addClass('showAdvertisement').siblings().removeClass('showAdvertisement');
  }
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

It would basically look like this:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 3; x++){ 
if (isScrolledIntoView($('.wrapper.site-section:nth-child(' + x + ')')) === true) {
  if ($('.desktop').length > 0) {
    $('.sidebar li').removeClass('showAdvertisement');
    $('.sidebar li:nth-child(' + (x + 3) + ')').addClass('showAdvertisement');
  }
}
}
```

Im unfamiliar with the exact context youre using this in, so be careful for the "number is not a valid string" error, but that's easily fixed.